# How to write to ipod from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sync, music, rhythmbox, ipod

I recently sent my ipod (5th Generation ipod with video) for a new battery and an SSD to replace the hard drive. The repair shop tested it and said it worked, it came back containing a single song which does play.

Before being sent away I used to have no problem adding music to the ipod using Rhythmbox. But since it's come back I have been unable to add any songs. On Rhythmbox I get an error dialogue saying "Error transferring track, could not open resource for writing.".

I have also tried gtkpod, and I get a message about the ipod being read-only.

I suspect that the problem might be that the repair shop updated the OS on the ipod, and that the libraries necessary to interact with the updated OS are not available in Ubuntu 18.04.

If anyone has any thoughts on how to fix this issue I'd be very grateful. I have considered replacing the OS with Rockbox, but that does not yet have an installer with support in Ubuntu 18.04.

Edit.

When I type mount in the terminal I get (at the end, after a lot of other entries):

```
/dev/sdb3 on /media/eddy/iPod type hfsplus (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,umask=22,uid=1000,gid=1000,nls=utf8,uhelper=udisks2)
```

I assume that ro means read only. How do I mount it for read write? The command

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb3 /media/eddy/iPod
```

doesn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: It could be a `mount` issue. In a ternimal window, type `mount`

Comment: @waltinator Thanks. I've added what looks to me to be the relevant line in the output from mount to my question.